# Metal flake paint

Tags: repainting

I used a paint that had metal flakes so magnets would stick.  Wanted to repaint the wall, but the wall was coarse from the metal that was in the paint.  Sanded it but in some places the wall still has some imperfections.  What can I do to cover imperfections?

Comment: Hi Anne, photos would help a lot.

Answer (score 1):

I’m not sure there is a perfect solution to what you want to do but here are a few options.

1. Try scraping with a putty knife rather than sanding.  I’d recommend starting with an angle of no more than about 15 degrees from the wall and a clean sharp knife around 3 inches wide.  You can slowly increase the angle to get more pressure, but keep the blade straight so you don’t nick the wall. This might or might not be the best/easiest solution if the flakes come off.
2. Use thicker paint. Depending on the size of the flakes, you may be able to get away with a thicker paint, such as a paint/primer mix or ceiling paint.
3. If the flakes are too large and won’t come off you can skim coat the wall.  This will work but if you have never done it before, you may want to watch some videos to get an idea how to do it right.